# change value in dict from datasets Hugging face

Tags: dictionary, dataset

I want to train model on the Wikitext-2-v1 training corpus(https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikitext).
I tried to remove punctuation in each line, which from what I find is a dictionary, i.e., each line is a dictionary, so I tried to update the value, but after the loop, I checked the value, there is nothing changed.

```
%pip install datasets
from datasets import list_datasets, load_dataset, list_metrics, load_metric
dataset = load_dataset('wikitext', 'wikitext-2-v1', split =['train','validation','test'])

for i in range(len(dataset[0])):

   for k,v in dataset[0][i].items():

       v = v.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

   dataset[0][i]['text'] = v
```

Here is a one line example {'text': ' = Valkyria Chronicles III = \n'}
after the loop it keeps same, but I want it to be {'text': '  Valkyria Chronicles III'}

Comment: if my answer is correct, please accept it as the correct answer. Stack Overflow is gamified and answerers are very motivated by these points and ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `translate` code is good and doing what it's supposed to.

I believe the `Dataset` type does not support item assignment. (You can't change it.) Normally this raises a `TypeError` but you managed to code it in a way to avoid that. You may need to build up a new a new datastructure with your translated data as you go.

*Note also that it is rather strange they way you iterate through `items()` but only use the `text` one. Seems to me either explicitly use only `text` or explicitly handle every one.*